# Visual Studio 2013 design view is very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm now coding C++/CLI application using Visual Studio 2013 professional.
There is a problem when I use "design view".

After I edit some codes, I save it and try to back to form "design view", screen always goes to white-out.
Then form appears after around 20 seconds.
Very slow to switch from code editor to design view.

I searched solutions against this problem, but I could not find any effective one.

thanks.

---

Thank you for your suggestion. > Hans Passant

Now I prepared small code. I reduced InitializeComponent() from 852 to 15 lines.
Although switching time loss was also reduced from 20 to 5 seconds,
I think it is not enough.. somewhat wrong (short whiteout remains).

Source.cpp, MyForm.cpp, MyForm.h

```
//-----
//Source.cpp

#include "MyForm.h"
using namespace Project1;

[STAThreadAttribute]

int main(){
    MyForm fm;
    fm.ShowDialog();
    return 0;
}


//-----
//MyForm.cpp

#include "MyForm.h"


//-----
//MyForm.h

#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/////////////////////////////////////////other functions/////////////////////////////////////////////////

namespace Project1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>

    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->ReadOnly = true;
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(138, 19);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 21;
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 12);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(164, 49);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();
        }
#pragma endregion
    };
}
```

Comment: Hmm, no, this is not a common complaint.  You'd better keep an eye on Task Manager's Processes tab, some odds that your anti-malware product is acting up.  By far the most common reason for a "white out".  Try another machine next.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I watched processes when switch back to design view, but only the process of devenv.exe acted up to 8% CPU, not any anti-malware products. And I knew that this problem occurs in another my PC (same win7 x64 machine). Screen "white out" was an exaggerated expression, sorry. I mean that "design view" white out and hourglass appears.

Comment: How many cores does your processor have?  How many lines of code do you see in the InitializeComponent() method?

Comment: 6 core CPU x 2 (total 12 cores).
There are 852 lines without comments in InitializeComponent().
Is it reasonable speed on this situation?

Comment: No.  You are going to have to show us repro code to get any help.